# How to match a list of strings in a tab-separated matrix file

Tags: perl

I am having two files:

1. Text file having a list of miRNA targets.
2. Text file having a miRNA as header and its corresponding targets.
   There are common targets present in both the files.

Sample File 1.

```
CDK6
CCNE1
CDC25A
STAT5A
RAVER2
RHOC
KLK10
BDNF
NFKB1
CXCR4
ROCK1
HUWE1
```

Sample file 2 is a matrix as follows

```
hsa-miR-29a-3p  hsa-miR-15b-5p  hsa-let-7c-5p   hsa-miR-222-3p  hsa-miR-99a-5p  hsa-miR-493-3p
CDK6    CCNE1   CDC25A  STAT5A  RAVER2  RHOC
RAN RECK    TGFBR1  CDKN1B  FGFR3   MAP2K7
BACE1   BCL2    TRIM71  BCL2L11 SERPINE1    FZD4
DNMT3A  CCND1   HMGA2   SOD2    IGF1R   HNRNPU
DNMT3B  VEGFA   MYC MMP1    MTOR    ABHD2
COL4A2  EIF4A1  DICER1  FOXO3   AGO2    SRSF11
```

The output file required is:

```
CDK6      1  0  0  0  0  0
CCNE1     0  1  0  0  0  0
CDC25A    0  0  1  0  0  0
```

---

```
open (FH,"sample_down.txt");
open (FILE,"sample_ref.txt");
while (<FH>) {
    chomp;
    $_ =~ s/\r//;
    if (/^hsa/) {
           $header=$_;
           @head=split (/\t/,$header);
           for (@head) {
               $h=$_;
               $hash1{$h}="$h";
           }
    } else {
        @target=split (/\t/,$_);
        for (@target) {
            $t=$_;
            $hash{$h}{$t}="$t";
        }
    }
}
while (<FILE>) {
    chomp;
    $_ =~ s/\r//;
    $ref =$_;
    foreach $v (keys %hash) {
             print "$v\n";
             if (exists $hash{$h}{$ref}) {
                 #print "$ref\t11\n";
             } else {
                 #print "$ref\t00000\n";
             }
    }
}
```

It will be great if someone can help me with the same.

Comment: What problems are you having? What is your question?

Comment: You should always use `use strict; use warnings;`. Otherwise errors will be silent, and you will miss critical information.

Comment: I am not able to print the output in the desired form and since all the reference are matching in d matrix file it is giving 1 to all the targets. I dont know maybe the file shud be read line by not instead of being read tab seperated.

Comment: All your print statements were commented out, so I removed them from your code to condense the code. You are reading line by line. It is not clear what you are trying to do. It looks like you are searching for the 3 first words in file1, and counting the occurrence per column in file2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `:crlf` layer so you don't have to remove the `\r` explicitly.

First, read the second file, remember where each target was found. Then, read the first file and for each target, print the remembered information.

```perl
#! /usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw{ say };

my $target_file = shift;
my $miRNA_file  = shift;

open my $miRNA_fh, '<:crlf', $miRNA_file or die $!;
my @header = split ' ', <$miRNA_fh>;
my %found;
while (<$miRNA_fh>) {
    chomp;
    my @t = split;
    for my $i (0 .. $#t) {
        $found{ $t[$i] }[$i] = 1;
    }
}

open my $target_fh, '<:crlf', $target_file or die $!;
while (my $t = <$target_fh>) {
    chomp $t;
    say join "\t", $t, map $found{$t}[$_] // 0, 0 .. $#header;
}
```

From your data it seems there couldn't be several 1's in the same line or column. My code is general, i.e. this restriction is not applied. Applying it would probably change the code a lot.